# Show decimals only if the cell has while showing custom text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a row of cells with numeric values. I'd like to produce the following effect:

```
---------------------------
|Cell value | Cell result |
---------------------------
|2          | 2 kg        |
|1.43       | 1.43 kg     |
|9.5764     | 9.58 kg     |
|3.2        | 3.2 kg      |
---------------------------
```

Basically,

- I want them to always show "kg" after the value that is entered.
- Any decimal value entered need to be rounded up to 2 decimal places; if there are no decimal places, it's going to show the whole number.

I've formatted cells to `0" kg"`so it always show  the kilograms.

As for showing only decimals if necessary, I've used the formula `=ROUND(X, 2)` on each cell to only show two decimals (*X* being the value I introduce).

**Question:** However when I type `=ROUND(2.5, 2)` it displays `3 kg` instead of `2.5 kg`. Why is it? Do you have other possible solutions?

**Edit 1**

I've changed the cell formatting to `0.##" kg"` and it works just like I want. Now the problem is if I use `=ROUND(10, 2)` it displays `10. kg` with that additional point right after the number.

Comment: try =FIXED(10,2)

Comment: Just changing that doesn't work. After applying it, it shows _10.00 kg_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the numbers in column A, use the Round() function in column B and then format with Custom format "General k\g". See screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution based on what I understand your requirement.  Use FIXED function to first round it to 2 decimals and check for last three digits, if .00 use only integer portion and concatenate with 'kg' if last digit is zero round to only 1 decimal else round to two decimals.

Assuming your data is in column B, try this formula in column C

```
=IF(RIGHT(FIXED(B1,2),3)=".00",CONCATENATE(INT(B1)," kg"),IF(RIGHT(FIXED(B1,2),1)="0",CONCATENATE(FIXED(B1,1)," kg"),CONCATENATE(FIXED(B1,2)," kg")))
```

[image]